# Share big Bitmap ImageView between two activities

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, android-activity, android-imageview

I have an ImageView in which I load a large image (3264x2448). The image is slightly altered with effects before it's loaded into the ImageView. After that I want to load a new Activity, but I also want to show the image from the first activity in the second activity.

So I need a way to copy the Bitmap over to the second activity.

I can't really put it in an `Intent`, because the image is too big for that?

I really need a way to share that image between `Activities`, because the image will be altered in each `Activity`.

What is a good way to share the image between different Activities?

Comment: It's very bad idea to share your image instead of share ImagePath and Load image on Demand.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

it has a transform option that you use to "create your effects" in

it caches the saved bitmap on disk, so when you load it next time in a different activity, it may load the transformed one

Answer (score 0):

Keep your image on the SD Card and fetch it from there in each of your activity and give the desired effect you wanna give to it.